# Why Java let us instantiate an Interface in Anonymous Classes when overriding their members, isn't it forbidden to instantiate an interface?

Tags: java

I know that Interfaces in Java cannot be instantiated because they are only Method Signatures and also they don't have implementations, we can only implement them throug children classes/interfaces. But when learning for the first time Anonymous Classes now I know that indeed I can instantiate an interface, doesn't suppose to be forbidden?

```
interface Saludadores {
    void saludar();
}

public class training3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Saludadores saludador = new Saludadores() {
            @Override
            public void saludar() {
                System.out.println("Hola, mundo!");
            }
        };
        
        saludador.saludar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your interface `Saludadores` is known as a functional interface and can be implemented by a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) since Java 8.

Comment: This is a special syntax that creates an anonymous innerclass.

Comment: You are not instantiating an interface. You are instantiating an anonymous class.

Comment: Hint:  `System.out.println(saludador.getClass());`

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous inner class is not the intiating of the interface.
Its the creation of an anonymous class that implements the interface referenced.

This is just a local initating of a class with its implementation.

Like abra mentioned in comments, how you have defined the interface it is a functional interface, from java 8 onwards your code could rewritten to:

```
interface Saludadores {
    void saludar();
}

public class training3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Saludadores saludador = () -> System.out.println("Hola, mundo!");
        saludador.saludar();
    }
}
```